# How to check if one sknode touched another

Tags: swift, nodes, skspritenode, intersect

I’m making a game in which one SKSpriteNode needs to touch another SKSpriteNode in order to beat the opponent.

```
 func intersects(node: SKSpriteNode) -> Bool {
            if ball.intersects(ygB) == true{
                ylicount = ylicount - 1
                yourlivescount.text = "\(ylicount)"
                if ylicount == 0{
                    self.view!.window!.rootViewController!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GameOverViewController", sender: self)
                }
            }else if ball.intersects(egB) == true{
                   elicount = elicount - 1;

                  enemylivescount.text = "\(elicount)"
                    if elicount == 0{
                        levelcount += 1
                        lccalc += 1
                        ball.physicsBody?.restitution =  (ball.physicsBody?.restitution)! - 0.000065416191
                        ep.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ball.position.x, duration: 0.5 - (lccalc * 0.00001916151134)))
                        elicount += 3
                        ball.position.x = 0
                        ball.position.y = 0
                    }

}
```

Essentially, there are two goals: yg and eg. ygB is an invisible SKNode around yg, and egB is the same for eg. The code is supposed to act accordingly if the ball intersects ygB or egB

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Give the both nodes you want to touch with each other a SKPhyiscs body .dynamic. Secondly , set up collision detection with bit masks. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicscontactdelegate